# How can I collapse this into just one row

Tags: ruby

I have the following ruby code:

```ruby
@averages = Array.new
weekly_averages.each do |average|

  yr = average.date.to_s[0..3].to_i
  wk = average.date.to_s[4..5].to_i
  prices = Array.new
  prices << { locale: average.locale, price: average.average }

  @averages << { :year => yr, :week => wk, :prices => prices }

end
```

This results into a table like this

```
Week Ending Date Product    Nairobi  Mombasa   Kisumu    Nakuru  Eldoret
38  2014-09-21  Dry Maize   3,140.00                
38  2014-09-21  Dry Maize           2,216.67            
38  2014-09-21  Dry Maize                     2,513.13      
38  2014-09-21  Dry Maize                               3,362.50    
38  2014-09-21  Dry Maize                                        2,311.43`
```

How can I collapse this into just one row, for instance:

```html
Week Ending Date   Product  Nairobi Mombasa Kisumu  Nakuru   Eldoret
38  2014-09-21  Dry Maize 3,140   2216.67 2,513.13 3,362.50 2,311.43
```

Comment: How can I collapse this into just one row?

Comment: The answer depends on how you would like the rows grouped. Do you want them grouped by week, product, or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) and iterate by the elements already grouped by date:

```
@averages = weekly_averages.group_by(&:date).map do |date, averages|
  yr = date.to_s[0..3].to_i
  wk = date.to_s[4..5].to_i
  prices = averages.map { |average| { locale: average.locale, price: average.average } }
  { year: yr, week: wk, prices: prices }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's begin by creating some data:

```
A = Struct.new :week, :ending_date, :product, :locale, :average

weekly_averages = [
  A.new(38, '2014-09-21', 'Dry Maize', 'Kakuru',  '3362.50'),
  A.new(38, '2014-09-21', 'Dry Maize', 'Mombasa', '2216.67'),
  A.new(38, '2014-09-21', 'Dry Maize', 'Kisuma',  '2513.13'),
  A.new(38, '2014-09-21', 'Dry Maize', 'Nairobi', '3140.00'),
  A.new(38, '2014-09-21', 'Dry Maize', 'Eldoret', '2311.43'),
  A.new(39, '2014-09-28', 'Dry Maize', 'Kakuru',  '3105.61'),
  A.new(39, '2014-09-28', 'Dry Maize', 'Mombasa', '2060.12'),
  A.new(38, '2014-09-21', 'Coffee',    'Eldoret', '1841.43'),
  A.new(38, '2014-09-21', 'Coffee',    'Kakuru',  '2187.66'),
]
```

You'll see that I modified your example by adding results for a second product (`'Coffee'`) and for a second week (week `39`). Moreover, not all locales have values for the added results.

I will assume the ending date depends only on the week. If so, we can deal with that with a hash (if not, you can treat it I have treated other attributes below):

```
week_end_date = weekly_averages.each_with_object({}) { |i,h|
  h[i.week] = i.ending_date }    
  #=> {38=>"2014-09-28", 39=>"2014-09-28"}
```

In what order do you want the rows? I'll assume you want to order them by week, and for each week, by product. (Just change the following as appropriate if you want a different ordering.) In what order do you want the products? Alphabetical? As specified? I'll assume you want to specify the product order:

```
products = ['Dry Maize', 'Coffee']
  #=> ["Dry Maize", "Coffee"]
```

We need a new data structure with elements ordered the same as the rows of the table, I will first create a hash whose keys are arrays of the two attributes used for sorting the data (`week` and `product`). This uses the form of the method [Hash#update](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that employs a block (here `{ |_,o,n| o.merge(n)}`) to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged:

```
averages = weekly_averages.each_with_object({}) { |i,h|
  h.update([i.week, i.product]=>{ i.locale => i.average }) { |_,o,n|
    o.merge(n) } }
  #=> {[38, "Dry Maize"]=>
  #       {"Kakuru"=>"3362.50", "Mombasa"=>"2216.67", "Kisuma"=>"2513.13",
  #        "Nairobi"=>"3140.00", "Eldoret"=>"2311.43"},
  #    [39, "Dry Maize"]=>{"Kakuru"=>"3105.61", "Mombasa"=>"2060.12"},
  #    [38, "Coffee"]=>{"Eldoret"=>"1841.43", "Kakuru"=>"2187.66"}}
```

Now use [Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) to sort the elements of `averages` and then convert the result (an array of key-value pairs) back into a hash;

```
sorted_averages = Hash[averages.sort_by { |(week, product),_|
  [week, products.index(product)] }]
  #=> {[38, "Dry Maize"]=>{"Kakuru"=>"3362.50", "Mombasa"=>"2216.67",
  #       "Kisuma"=>"2513.13", "Nairobi"=>"3140.00", "Eldoret"=>"2311.43"},
  #    [38, "Coffee"]=>{"Eldoret"=>"1841.43", "Kakuru"=>"2187.66"},
  #    [39, "Dry Maize"]=>{"Kakuru"=>"3105.61", "Mombasa"=>"2060.12"}}
```

We have two more things to specify. The first is the order of the locales (columns):

```
locales = %w| Nairobi    Mombasa   Kisuma    Kakuru  Eldoret |
  #=> ["Nairobi", "Mombasa", "Kisuma", "Kakuru", "Eldoret"]
```

Lastly, we need to specify the width and alignment of each column. To do that I'll create an array of hashes with keys `:label` (column label), `:width` (column width) and `:alignment` (left adjusted, centered or right-adjusted). The i<sup>th</sup> element of this array corresponds to the i<sup>th</sup> column:

```
fields = [{ label: "Week", width: 4, alignment: :left},
          { label: "Ending Date", width: "Ending Date".size + 2,
             alignment: :center },
          { label: "Product",
            width: (1+(weekly_averages.map {|i|
              i.product}.uniq << "Product").map(&:size).max),
            alignment: :left }
]
  #=> [{:label=>"Week", :width=>4, :alignment=>:left},
  #    {:label=>"Ending Date", :width=>13, :alignment=>:center},
  #    {:label=>"Product", :width=>10, :alignment=>:left}] 

locales.each { |l| fields <<
  { label: l,
    width: [1+l.size, 2 + weekly_averages.map { |i| i.average.size }.max].max,
    alignment: :right
  }
}

fields
  #=> [{:label=>"Week", :width=>4, :alignment=>:left},
  #    {:label=>"Ending Date", :width=>13, :alignment=>:center},
  #    {:label=>"Product", :width=>10, :alignment=>:left},
  #    {:label=>"Nairobi", :width=>11, :alignment=>:right},
  #    {:label=>"Mombasa", :width=>11, :alignment=>:right},
  #    {:label=>"Kisumu", :width=>11, :alignment=>:right},
  #    {:label=>"Nakuru", :width=>11, :alignment=>:right},
  #    {:label=>"Eldoret", :width=>11, :alignment=>:right}]
```

We can now print the table. First the column headers:

```
fields.each do |h|
  case h[:alignment]
  when :left           then print h[:label].ljust(h[:width])
  when :center         then print h[:label].center(h[:width])
  when :right          then print h[:label].rjust(h[:width])
  end
end
puts
```

then the body:

```
sorted_averages.each do |(week, product), g|
  fields.each do |h|
    s =
    case h[:label]
    when "Week"        then week.to_s
    when "Ending Date" then week_end_date[week]
    when "Product"     then product
    else g[h[:label]] || ''
    end

    case h[:alignment]
    when :left         then s = s.ljust(h[:width])
    when :center       then s = s.center(h[:width])
    when :right        then s = s.rjust(h[:width])
    end
    print s
  end
  puts
end

Week Ending Date Product     Nairobi  Mombasa   Kisuma   Kakuru  Eldoret
38   2014-09-21  Dry Maize   3140.00  2216.67  2513.13  3362.50  2311.43
38   2014-09-21  Coffee                                 2187.66  1841.43
39   2014-09-28  Dry Maize            2060.12           3105.61
```

Comment: Thanks Cary, I will check it out